# A simple for in statement causes an error

Tags: python, django

I wonder, what's wrong with this:

```
{% for x in [1, 2, 3] %}
    <p>{{x}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

An error:

```
'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for x in [1, 2, 3]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
   # .py
   data = {'key1': .... //dictionary, 'key2': .... // dictionary }

   # template
   {% for k, v in data['key1'].items %}
      <p>{{ k }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

An error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '['key1'].items' from 'data['key1'].items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django template language does not support literal lists. Either pass it in from the view, or use the [`make_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#make-list) filter on a string:

```
{% for x in "123"|make_list %}
```

Comment: How can I iterate via a dictionary? It returns me `Could not parse the remainder: '['key1'].items' from 'data['key1'].items'` where `data` is a dictionary and `key1` is also a dictionary which I want to iterate over.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that comment at all, or see how it is related to the original question.

Comment: But you are again trying to use unsupported syntax in a Django template. It's not Python; you can't use plain Python syntax there. All this is fully explained in the Django docs.